# Wordpress Theme Access Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am modifying a wordpress theme to have a mobile menu. However, I don't have much experience with WP or PHP, so I need you to tell me what function/code WP uses to access the pages on the top bar. Also, which doc should I modify? (The theme is Vantage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit header.php located in

```
wp-content/themes/vantage/header.php
```

## UPDATE

here is function on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/azeemhassni/ba075aaf70766d79ee23) i wrote for my project

```
function get_current_template_name($return = FALSE) {
        $files = get_included_files();
        $templateIndex = (count($files)-2);
        $string = $files[$templateIndex];
        $templateName = end(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $string));
        if($return) return $templateName;
        else echo $templateName;
}


// Calling | this will print the current template name
get_current_template_name(); 

// Calling with Bool Param 
$tmpl_file = get_current_template_name(TRUE);
if($tmpl_file == 'page.php') echo "this page is using default page template";
```

Comment: But what function do I use to access the names of the site pages? @AziBaloch